# Letting Gestures fall through to different Views on Android

Tags: android, gesture

I've got a custom View which wills the screen. I've built its onDraw code to support a pinch-zoom style of zooming in and out. The View itself handles all of this work.

Additionally though, I'd like to allow the user to swipe across the screen, either left or right, so that I can swap out that view with the view before or after (similar to a paging situation).

I was able to capture and respond to the swipe left and right using a GestureOverlayView, but now that overlay view is intercepting my pinch-zooming touch events. How can I allow those pinch-zooming touch events to fall through to the custom View will grabbing the swiping gestures up at the activity level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) with a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) instead of a GestureOverlayView.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/02/implement-swiping-page-effect-using.html

with a setup like this, the gesture detector should only accept left/right swipes, while the view currently displayed still controls the pinch-zoom effect

Comment: Perfect, this is a great solution. Thank you!